# C# - XElement and Culture

Tags: c#, .net, xelement, culture

I am having issues with XElement and Culture.

My local culture is French. Floating value are written with a comma instead of a point.

```
Console.WriteLine(1.1d);
//1,1
```

However when I put a double in an XElement, it is stored in american format.

```
XElement myXmlElement = new XElement("ADoubleElement", 1.1d);
Console.WriteLine(myXmlElement.Value);
//1.1
```

Therefore when I try to parse back the value of my XElement, I get a FormatException.

```
XElement myXmlElement = new XElement("ADoubleElement", 1.1d);
double myDouble = double.Parse(myXmlElement.Value);
//Throws a FormatException
```

I find this behaviour really strange. When I write a XDoucment, it is not written in the culture of the application or the thread but always in american culture.
Am I missing something ? I have some workaround to behave the way I expect but I do not find them very "clean".

```
//This will work
XElement myXmlElement = new XElement("ADoubleElement", 1.1d.ToString());
double myDouble = double.Parse(myXmlElement.Value);
//This will also work but if I write XElement, it will not have the correct Culture
XElement myXmlElement = new XElement("ADoubleElement", 1.1d);
double myDouble = (double)myXmlElement;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XML specification describes how data should be formatted, and that's why `XElement` does not use your culture - it follows XML specification (which is actually probably the same as `InvariantCulture`)

That's also why casting `XElement` to `double` works and `double.Parse` doesn't: it follows XML specification formats instead of local ones.

Answer (score 2):

`XElement` will always use `InvariantCulture` when converting to or from strings.
This is XML is meant to serialize data, and you don't want that to break when moving across cultures.

`Parse()` and `ToString()` use `CurrentCulture` by default.
This is because these functions are meant to be used when interacting with users, who expect to see numbers in their usual fashion.

You should [always](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182190.aspx) explicitly pass a culture when calling `Parse()` or `ToString()`.

Comment: I don't really think that is the reason. The reason more likely is what Marcin said: In XML, numbers are always formatted according to the invariant culture.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yes; that's why.

Comment: Ah, you changed your answer since/while I wrote my comment. Sneaky ;)